# Issue with paged list in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got  class named PagedList which looks like this:

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{

    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public bool HasPrevious
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.PageIndex > 0);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNext
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.PageIndex + 1 < this.TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.TotalCount = source.Count();
        this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

        this.AddRange(source.Skip(this.PageIndex * this.PageSize).Take(this.PageSize));
    }
}
```

In my **Customers** controller I use it like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    IRepository<UserInfo> profile = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<UserInfo>>();

        const int pageSize = 25;

        IQueryable<UserInfo> profiles = profile.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.LastName).AsQueryable<UserInfo>();

        var pagedCustomers = new PagedList<UserInfo>(profiles, page ?? 0, pageSize);

    return View(pagedCustomers);
}
```

And finally in my Index.cshtml file I set up my Model like so:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PagedList<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>>
```

And When I go Model. it's a huge list, nothing to do with the PagedList I created in the Customers controller.

Anyone got any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some text of what the model output looks like roughly?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your request

Comment: "And When I go Model. it's a huge list, nothing to do with the PagedList I created in the Customers controller." - explain what this means by way of example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PagedList is enumerable. To access individual UserInfo object use @foreach(var userInfo in Model)

Someone else mentioned about the use of IQueryable. It's a good practice to use ToArray() or ToList() at boundaries. Your repository is a boundary, so I would consider moving the paging logic to it and make it return either the PagedList object or the data necessary to construct one.

Answer (score 0):

Your model class right now is `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PagedList<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>>` as opposed to `PagedList<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>` - this is likely why you are seeing all of this strange data on your model.

[System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470798.aspx) is a component used to render models and shouldn't be the model itself. Change your model type to just `PagedList<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>` and it should work.

Comment: I changed the model to _@model PagedList<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>_ and I can see items from the PagedList class but nothing on UserInfo so I think I'm getting closer

Comment: The other issue might be your use of IQueryable... unless you're doing additional queries on the model after you serve it to your view, just try changing this to a regular old IEnumerable or IList - that way your view can enumerate through it properly.